# scipy.optimize.leastsq Fitting: minpack.error

Tags: python, scipy, least-squares

I am trying to run a code as shown below, it is a simple least square fit, for which I am hopping to get the inverted vars coefficient.

```
import numpy as np
def model(vars, x): 
  model = vars[0]*x[0]+vars[1]*x[1]+vars[2]
  return model
def residuals(vars, x, data):
  err = data - vars[0]*x[0]+vars[1]*x[1]+vars[2]
  return err

from scipy.optimize import leastsq
vars = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
x = np.genfromtxt('C:\Arrayx.txt')
data = np.resize(np.genfromtxt('C:\Data.txt'),(5,1))
out = leastsq(residuals, vars, args=(x, data))
```

*Arrayx.txt has the content as:*

```
240 0
7   86
241 184
478 92
244 90
```

*Data.txt has the content as:*

```
1.765
1.901
2.17
2.09
2.01
```

I got this 2 error messages when I run the code:
**minpack.error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.**
**ValueError: object too deep for desired array.**
I am new to python, any help on this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't actually with leastsq at all: it's with the way numpy array dimensionality works.

`x` and `data` are both two dimensional arrays, because of the way you loaded them (at least for `x`, it needs to be 2d anyway; `data` doesn't). Numpy indexing is (row,column). Your `x[0]` and `x[1]`, which I assume were meant to access the first and second *columns* of `x`, actually access the first and second (of 5) *rows*. Numpy tries to be helpful when you then add these 1x2 arrays to the 5x1 Data array. The result is an output from `residuals` that leastsq can't handle (try running residuals by itself).

What you likely want to do is access the first and second columns, multiply these by the correct var elements, and then add the (five) numbers to the five numbers in data. To get a column of x, you should do something like `x[:,0]` (all rows, column 0). The problem is, this returns a one-dimensional array, and you've explicitly made `data` two-dimensional with one column and five rows with the np.resize. You don't need that - data is really only one-dimensional, so we can remove the resize. The result is the following:

```
import numpy as np
def model(vars, x): 
  model = vars[0]*x[:,0]+vars[1]*x[:,1]+vars[2]
  return model
def residuals(vars, x, data):
  err = data - vars[0]*x[:,0]+vars[1]*x[:,1]+vars[2]
  return err

from scipy.optimize import leastsq
vars = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
x = np.genfromtxt('Arrayx.txt')
data = np.genfromtxt('Data.txt')
out = leastsq(residuals, vars, args=(x, data))
```